# Initializing a variable with childNodes out of an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, child-nodes

Can someone help explain what the following JavaScript syntax was meant to do:

```
  var tagLink_ar = document.getElementsByTagName('td');  

  **var x = tagLink_ar.childNodes, i=0, j;**                 // Not sure ???
```

This is from an older javascript function that no longer works in IE>9 or FF.

tagLink_ar of course is the array of TD tags, yet I have not previously seen a variable with an index element i and j, and can't find a similar descriptor in my research online. Does i just reference the starting element and j the length?

Thoughts on how to load x in a similar manner?

---

Makes sense it is a simple declaration for x, i and j. Yet getting a "TypeError: x is undefined".

Below is the function as a reference:

```
var tagLink_ar = document.getElementsByTagName('td');  
**var x = tagLink_ar.childNodes, i=0, j;**                 // Not sure ???

while(j == x[i++]){                                             
  if(j.nodeType == 1 && nodeName == 'div'){                     
     var viewDiv = getStyle(divElement, 'display');
     if (viewDiv == 'block'){                                   
       x[j].style.borderBottom = "1px solid #000000";
     }
   }
}
```

Noted the syntax error on the while, should have been j=x[i++], and j.nodeName

Comment: That's just a variable declaration that declares 3 variables: `x`, `i`, and `j`.

Comment: That codes makes no sense. `tagLink_ar` has indexes, where each element has a `childNodes`. What is this code supposed to do?

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara right - there's no "childNodes" property on a NodeList object.

Comment: If there is no `childNodes` property, then this creates it.

Comment: @rfornal: No, not at all.

Comment: @rfornal No it doesn't. `x` gets set to the default `undefined` property of `tagLink_ar`. It does not create a property on `tagLink_ar`.

Comment: Ooops, at a conference and didn't look at it close enough.  Thanks for the catch.  Glad it was just a comment ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no reasonable circumstance where `x` could have a `childNodes` property. `tagLink_ar` is a `NodeList`, and each of the elements *in that list* has a `childNodes` property.

There are a few other reasons why that code would never work. Did you copy it correctly?

To get the result the code was designed to have, you can do this (I'm including some sample HTML so that you can run it as a snippet):

```js
var tagLink_ar = document.getElementsByTagName('td'),
    children, i, j, node, viewDiv;

for (i = 0; i < tagLink_ar.length; i += 1) {
    children = tagLink_ar[i].childNodes;
    for (j = 0; j < children.length; j += 1) {
        node = children[j];

        if (node.nodeType === 1 && 
            node.nodeName.toLowerCase() === 'div' && 
            node.style.display === 'block') {
            
            node.style.borderBottom = "1px solid #000000";
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div>a</div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div style="display: block;">b</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div style="display: block;">c</div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div style="display: block;">b</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div>e</div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div>f</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax in question just initializes variables, albeit very confusingly.

```
var x = tagLink_ar.childNodes, i=0, j;
```

Is equivalent to

```
var x = tagLink_ar.childNodes;
var i = 0;
var j = undefined;
```